Sending custom event to WPF window from code-behind
I'm trying to subscribe to a custom event fired from code-behind in an EventTrigger element.  All the examples I can find are for events triggered by the front-end, but I want to do it the other way around.  Here is some example code, which is intended to trigger the animation every second:
Code behind:
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static readonly RoutedEvent RoutedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
               name: "TestRoutedEventName",
               routingStrategy: RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
               handlerType: typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
               ownerType: typeof(MainWindow));

        public event RoutedEventHandler Event
        {
            add { AddHandler(RoutedEvent, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(RoutedEvent, value); }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _ = new DispatcherTimer(
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000),
                DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                (sender, args) => RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(RoutedEvent)),
                App.Current.Dispatcher);
        }
    }

XAML:
<Window x:Class="WpfEventTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfEventTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="200">
    <StackPanel>
        <Viewbox Stretch="Fill" Width="100" Height="100">
            <Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
                <Path Fill="#FF0000" Name="Path">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry Figures="M 10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                    </Path.Data>
                    <Path.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="**WHAT DO I PUT IN HERE**">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Path"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color"
                                        From="Red" To="White" Duration="0:0:0.8" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Path.Triggers>
                </Path>
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

At the moment I'm just using a DispatcherTimer for simplicity, but the event needs to come from an external source.
Questions:

Is something like this possible?
If so, what syntax do I use to bind the RoutedEvent to the EventTrigger?
If not how do I do it?


If you write code in the view, then you can directly run storyboard. No need to define some event in the view itself. In your case perhaps a better idea is simply repeat animation. And every time I see [wpf] tag without [mvvm] I want to shout use MVVM, the earlier you start using it, the better.

@Sinatr Writing code in a view doesn't sound very MVVM to me, however would you be able to show me an example?

You most probably have handler method already. Why not calling the event's handler directly, instead of sending an event?

Ok, so you want to use MVVM. Then instead of calling view from viewmodel consider defining event in viewmodel and rise it whenever something should happens in the view. A much simple form of event is bool property, bind to this property from trigger, to trigger set property to true and then to false every time. As for code in the view, right, that's sometimes unavoidable. "Dirty" MVVM can be refactored into reusable behaviors.

@MichałTurczyn do you have an example?

Your event name doesn't match your event's name.
For name "TestRoutedEventName" the field should be named public static readonly RoutedEvent TestRoutedEventNameEvent, and event should be named public event RoutedEventHandler TestRoutedEventName.
Considering that the field will be named TestRoutedEventNameEvent and NS is xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfEventTest" you should write in XAML:
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="{x:Static local:MainWindow.TestRoutedEventNameEvent}">
    ...
</EventTrigger>

To make it work you have to trigger the event (call RaiseEvent) on the Path instance. Calling RaiseEvent on the window instance won't work.
Note: Since it's a bubbling event, calling RaiseEvent on any logical child of Path would also work, but Path can't have any logical children.

Thank you, this was helpful, and I have it working.  There were two key points here that made the difference:

Referring to the event by its text name in the XAML RoutedEvent="local:MainWindow.TestRoutedEventName" was enough for that.
Raising the event on Path


The only missing peace of the puzzle is that the markup never recognises that MainWindow.TestRoutedEventNameEvent is defined and gives me an invalid markup error.  Is there any way around that?

With the use of {x:Static ... markup it should stop complaining after successful build. The RoutedEvent Property is of RoutedEvent type. Directly assigning its value, without using a converter from string, always works the best.
